# Why SOQL 'select id name from folder' do not get 'My Personal Custom Folder' and 'Unfiled public reports'

Tags: soql, folder, reports-folder

Why SOQL 'select id name from folder' do not get 'My Personal Custom Folder' and 'Unfiled public reports'.
But when I use 'select OwnerId from Report', it will return the reports under these two folders?

Is it expected? How can I get two folders when I only select in folder table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's expected. Personal folders are not "real" Folder records, but are instead represented by a User Id. Likewise, Unfiled Public Reports is not a real folder either, but instead a special Id that represents reports that have not been filed in any other folder. There is no way to get at these folders because they do not really exist.